# Flexible carousel plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

I have a list of suppliers (fetched from DB), which acting like pagination buttons.
Each supplier has many items, it has to offer.

List of items will be displayed only for one supplier on the page.
Selecting i'th supplier, will reveal list of items for it, with nice sliding effect in JavaScript.

I'm looking for a carousel (list of scrollable items) plugin, that will allow me to delegate page selection control to specific HTML element. In my case, i need to tell to the carousel plugin, that for pagination, i'd like to use list of suppliers.

Is there any jQuery plugin around ?

I found [jQuery Carousel](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) plugin, but it does't offers such a feature. It automatically creates HTML for pagination buttons.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with [jquery tools scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) has been very good and I recommend all jquery tools anytime.

**Edit**: While I don't completely understand your exact use case, the scrollable plugin is very flexible and does not come in the way.